# Redux initial state gets mutated even when using Object.assign

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

This is a simple replication of a problem i encounter in an actual app. 
https://jsfiddle.net/zqb7mf61/

Basically, if you clicked on 'Update Todo" button, the text will change from "Clean Room" to "Get Milk". "Clean Room" is a value in the initial State of the reducer. Then in my React Component, I actually try to clone the state and mutate the clone to change the value to "Get Milk" (Line 35/36). Surprisingly, the initial State itself is also mutated even though I try not to mutate it (as seen in line 13 too).

I am wondering why Object.assign does not work for redux.

Here are the codes from the jsFiddle.

REDUX

```
const initState = {
    task: {id: 1, text: 'Clean Room'}
}

// REDUCER
function todoReducer (state = initState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
   case 'UPDATE_TODO':
        console.log(state)
        let newTodo = Object.assign({}, state)  // here i'm trying to not make any changes. But i am surpise that state is already mutated.
      return newTodo
    default:
        return state;
  }
}

// ACTION CREATORS:
function updateTodo () {
    return {type: 'UPDATE_TODO'};
}


// Create Store
var todoStore = Redux.createStore(todoReducer);
```

REACT COMPONENT

```
//REACT COMPONENT
 class App extends React.Component{
    _onSubmit = (e)=> {
    e.preventDefault();
    let newTodos = Object.assign({}, this.props.todos)  // here i clone the redux state so that it will not be mutated, but i am surprise that it is mutated and affected the reducer.
    newTodos.task.text = 'Get Milk'
    console.log(this.props.todos)
    this.props.updateTodo();
  }

    render(){
    return (
        <div>
        <h3>Todo List:</h3>
        <p> {this.props.todos.task.text} </p>

        <form onSubmit={this._onSubmit} ref='form'>
          <input type='submit' value='Update Todo' />
        </form>      

      </div>
     );
  }
 }

// Map state and dispatch to props
function mapStateToProps (state) {
    return {
    todos: state
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch) {
    return Redux.bindActionCreators({
    updateTodo: updateTodo
  }, dispatch);
 }
  // CONNECT TO REDUX STORE
 var AppContainer = ReactRedux.connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use `Object.assign` in both the reducer as in the component. This function only copies the first level of variables within the object. You will get a new main object, but the references to the objects on the 2nd depth are still the same.

E.g. you just copy the reference to the `task` object around instead of actually creating a new `task` object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Deep_Clone

---

Apart from that it would be better to not load the whole state into your component and handle actions differently. Lets just solve this for now. You will have to create a new task object in your `onSubmit` instead of assigning a new text to the object reference. This would look like this:

```
newTodos.task = Object.assign({}, newTodos.task, {text: 'Get Milk'})
```

Furthermore to actually update the store, you will have to edit your reducer as you now assign the current state to the new state. This new line would look like this:

```
let newTodo = Object.assign({}, action.todos)
```

Comment: Brilliant answer. I always thought that Object.assign does a deep clone. No wonder when i use JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(todos)), it will work as I expected but not Object.assign.

Comment: @Mikroware great answer, just noticed one typo, you probably meant to write `newTodos.task = Object.assign({}, this.props.todos.task, {text: 'Get Milk'})`

Comment: @KevinK. my answer is quite old, but I don't think it matters. My answer was to only replace the original line where `'Get Milk'` gets assigned. The `this.props.todos` object was already shallow copied into `let newTodos` in the line above. Of course it can be written way more elegant, however my intention was to provide an answer with minimum changes.